# Finding a string in a file on a file system using Grep

Tags: grep, find

I need to do a search on a number of files in a file system to look for a string "RUSH2112". I have completed the following command however I am not sure if this is correct. I stand in the mounted file system.

```
find . -type f -exec grep -i1 "Rush2112" {} \;
```

Comment: What Unix are you on and what does the `-1` option do with your `grep`?

Comment: What would be your expected output? The lines containing the matches, or the filenames that contain the string, or ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To look for a *string* (not a regular expression) without caring for case, use `grep -iF STRING` (where `STRING` should be the quoted string you are looking for).

To recurse over all regular files in a directory hierarchy, do

```
find . -type f -exec grep -iF STRING /dev/null {} +
```

The main difference between this and your command is that this will execute `grep` for groups of found files.  Your command would run `grep` once for each found file which may be slower if there are many files.  It's the `+` at the end that makes this difference.

The other difference is that since `grep` is invoked with more than one file, its output will contain the pathnames of the files where matches are found.  The `/dev/null` is there to *force* this behaviour in case `grep` happens to be invoked with only a single file.  You may use `grep`'s `-H` option instead of including `/dev/null` if your implementation of `grep` has that non-standard (but common) option.

Some implementation of `grep` also has the option to recurse directories by itself, without the help of `find`.  This is often done with an `-R` option:

```
grep -R -iF STRING .
```

Note that GNU `grep` also has a `-r` option that is slightly different from its `-R` option (with `-r`, symbolic links will not be followed, which would more closely mimic the behaviour you'd get with running `grep` via `find . -type f`).

---

If what you're after is to find only the pathnames of the files that contain the string and not necessarily the actual lines from those files that match, then you may do that in a number of different ways (all largely analogous to what's mentioned above).

- Use `grep -q` as a test on each file:

  ```
  find . -type f -exec grep -qiF STRING {} ';' -print
  ```
- Use `grep -l` across groups of files found by `find`:

  ```
  find . -type f -exec grep -ilF STRING {} +
  ```
- Use recursive `grep -l`:

  ```
  grep -R -ilF STRING .
  ```

If you are wanting to do further processing of the files that contain the given string, then I would go with the first of these alternatives:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -qiF STRING {} ';' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        # Process "$pathname" here
    done' sh {} +
```

or, doing the `grep` inside the in-line script:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        if grep -qiF STRING "$pathname"; then
            # Process "$pathname" here
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)